# How to display a google map inside modal bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, bootstrap-4

I would to disply inside the modal a google map withtout to use the api.
Inside the loop the coordonae can change (I write just a constant for this example)
I tried this. The modal appear but not the map.

Thank you

my loop

```
 $i = 0;
        foreach ($result as $value) {
          $geolocalisation = '
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GeoModal'. $i .'">' . Core::getDef('modules_test') . '</a> |
          <div class="modal fade" id="GeoModal'. $i .'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">-----
               <div id="mapCanvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          ';
```

the script must display the map

```
 $geolocalisation .= '
<script>
            function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.219987, 4.396237),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),
    mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.219987, 4.396237)
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>
';

          $methods[]= ['id'     => $value->id,
                       'title'  => '<br> ' . $value->name . ' ' .  $value->address . ' ' .  $value->addressOptional . ' ' .  $value->locality. ' '  .  $value->city . ' ' .  $value->postalCode . ' ' .  $value->partialClosed . ' ' .  $geolocalisation,
                       'cost'   => 5.50
                      ];
$i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi? here is your google map with your bootstrap 4 modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d116862.54554679655!2d90.40409584970706!3d23.749000170125925!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1550040341458" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution uses google maps embed api and NOT google map javascript API. I would go so far to say this does not answer the question at all

Comment: As observed above this code does not use google map javascript API. its more of an hack

Answer (score 0):

You need to init map on button click to opened modal and create the function to init map with parameter that contain your latitude and longitude location maybe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
 <style>
       /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <!-- add attribute data-lat="5.134515" data-long="97.151759" to pass location data -->
  <button type="button" id="open" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-lat="5.134515" data-long="97.151759">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
           <!-- show map here -->
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
   function init(myLoc) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLoc
        });
      var opt = {
            center: myLoc,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opt);
        marker.setMap(map);
    };

$("#open").click(function(){
// get latitude and longitude that pass from open modal button
    init(new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('long')));
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```